# headless firefox failed on aws amazon linux

Tags: linux, firefox, aws, headless, amazon

I have followed the procedures as described in [https://lambda-linux.io/blog/2015/01/28/announcing-firefox-browser-support-for-amazon-linux/

However, when I tried to start up firefox, I am still getting

```
$ firefox
```

> XPCOMGlueLoad error for file /usr/local/firefox/libmozgtk.so:
>
> libgtk-3.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory Couldn't load XPCOM.

Answer (score 4):

Just found out the issue.  The above approach works with the older version of firefox (45.0.1) but not the latest one (46.0.1) that would call the libgtk3 and libgdk3.  Will carry on using 45.0.1 for now.